# MYSQL STR_TO_DATE not returning desired results

Tags: mysql, date

I am trying to run a function to return the difference of days between two dates. For this reason, I fetch two dates based on a date parameter (this is working fine). Next, I use the parameter date `pdate` to construct dates if they are not found in a table. This construction of dates is not working as desired. Following is the code:

```
`DELIMITER $$

USE payrolldb001 $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS NoOfWorkingDays $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION NoOfWorkingDays(P_EmployeeID INT,pdate             DATE) RETURNS INT(10) 
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN

DECLARE v_FromDate DATE;
DECLARE todate DATE;
DECLARE workingdays INT;
DECLARE shiftoff INT;
DECLARE gazzetted INT;

SET v_FromDate=(SELECT cp.FromDate FROM current_payroll cp
               INNER JOIN employees e ON e.employeeid=P_EmployeeID AND e.CompanyCode=cp.CompanyCode 
               AND e.SubOfficeCode=cp.SubOfficeCode
               WHERE pdate BETWEEN cp.FromDate AND cp.ToDate);
IF (v_FromDate IS NOT NULL) THEN              
SET todate=(SELECT cp.ToDate FROM current_payroll cp
               INNER JOIN employees e ON e.employeeid=P_EmployeeID AND e.CompanyCode=cp.CompanyCode 
               AND e.SubOfficeCode=cp.SubOfficeCode
               WHERE pdate BETWEEN cp.FromDate AND cp.ToDate);
    ELSE 
        SET v_FromDate=STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(pdate),'',MONTH(pdate)-1,'-21'),"%d%m%Y");
        SET todate=STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(pdate),'-',MONTH(pdate),'-20'),"%d%m%Y");

END IF;

SET workingdays = DATEDIFF(todate,v_FromDate);

WHILE  v_FromDate<=todate DO
     SET shiftoff= `isShiftOff`(P_EmployeeID,v_FromDate);
    IF (shiftoff=0) THEN
        SET gazzetted = `GazettedHoliday`(v_FromDate,P_Employeeid);
         SET workingdays = workingdays-gazzetted;
    ELSE
        SET workingdays=workingdays-shiftoff;
    END IF;

    -- RESET QUERY CACHE;
    -- FLUSH QUERY CACHE;
    SET v_FromDate = ADDDATE(v_FromDate,1); 
END WHILE;

RETURN workingdays ; 

END$$

DELIMITER ;`
```

The error I am getting is as follows:
`Incorrect datetime value: '2013-8-21' for function str_to_date`
which is in the conversion for `v_FromDate`.

Answer (score 0):

A fix would be to change the setting of date variables as:

`SET v_FromDate=STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(pdate),'-',MONTH(pdate)-1,'-',21),"%Y-%c-%d");`

`SET todate=STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(pdate),'-',MONTH(pdate),'-',20),"%Y-%c-%d");`